# API-less linkedin follow button

Tags: url, linkedin-api

I've been scouring the interwebs all morning and haven't been able to find a working example of a simple FOLLOW url for linkedin.
I would like to create a button on my social tab which wouldn't only link to the company page but also automatically make you follow it.

The url given by the follow button on the page itself isn't working from another machine.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a bunch,
Shay

Answer (score 0):

This is your best option: http://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company , it does what you need.

Comment: Close but no cigar. Using their plugin constricts me to using the icon, but I already have a set of social icons.

Comment: You can always use jQuery to change the images, but Linkedin doesn't recommend doing it this way. They recommend doing so via the API.